# How to unbind float numbering from document structure

Tags: floats, numbering, koma-script

I want to see behaviour as in standard classes, where floats use global numbering.

```
\documentclass{scrreport}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Исходные данные для рассматриваемой задачи}
    \centering
    \label{tabl:1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Номер & ~~~~$X$~~~~ & ~~~~$Y$~~~~ & ~~~~$R$~~~~ & ~~~~Цвет~~~~          \\
        \hline
        1     & 100         & 170         & 30          & \color{red} красный   \\
        2     & 100         & 90          & 60          & \color{yellow} жёлтый \\
        3     & 230         & 250         & 50          & \color{blue} синий    \\
        4     & 130         & 240         & 60          & \color{green} зелёный \\
        5     & 300         & 130         & 30          & \color{green} зелёный \\
        6     & 200         & 150         & 90          & \color{red} красный   \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

I want:

[image]

Comment: `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}`.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to specify these for other floats too. Is there a single command for this?

Comment: No, but I don't see what's so hard with `\counterwithout` calling it two times (maybe 3 or 4 if you have many different floats).

Comment: But maybe there is some option in KOMA, that I'm not aware of.